# Как получить значение выбранного фильтра в qt?

Tags: c++, qt5

Всем привет! 
Пытаюсь сохранить файл с помощью

```
saveFileDialog->getSaveFileName(this,
            tr("Save to file"), "",
            tr("*.wav;;*.alsa;;*.raw;;*.null;;All Files (*)"));
QString saveFilterName  = saveFileDialog->selectedNameFilter();
```

но в saveFilterName записывается All Files какой бы фильтр я не выбрал в диалоговом окне. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значение выбранного фильтра в диалоговом окне. Хочу чтобы файл сохранялся с выбранным в фильтре расширением. Буду благодарен за примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
QString selectedFilter;
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "", "", "*.txt;;*.doc;;*.*", &selectedFilter);
qDebug()<<selectedFilter<<fileName;
```

Кстати расширение согласно выбранному фильтру добавляется автоматически и добавлять его руками не надо.

upd:
Вот вывод `qDebug` по моему коду, если в диалоге забить имя файла `123`:

```
"*.txt" "D:/Documents/progs/build-SaveFileDialogFilter-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/123.txt"
```

И только что перепроверил у себя пример loading and saving, результат сохраняется с расширением. Какая у вас версия Qt, какая ось и как именно вы выбираете имя файла?

Comment: Я собрал пример http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part6-addressbook-cpp.html , но и в нем файл сохраняется без расширения. Например сохраняется файл с именем "newFile" без расширения .abk

Comment: смотрите upd в моем ответе